Endpoint fractional Sobolev estimate: show that $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)\not\hookrightarrow L^\infty$
In a note I found the following fact which the author didn't prove nor did she cite any reference:

For  $\alpha >0$, let $H^\alpha(\Bbb R^n)$ denote the space of tempered distributions $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$ so that $$\|f\|_{H^\alpha}:= {\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}{(1+\|\xi\|^2)}^\alpha |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi\right)}^{1/2}< \infty\:.$$
Then for any ball $B \subset \Bbb R^n$, the following inequality fails for any constant $c_B>0$,
$${\|f\|}_{L^\infty(B)} \le c_B {\|f\|}_{H^{n/2}}\cdots (*)$$

My attempt: It seems to me that she is referring to some borderline Sobolev. So I decided to simplify the RHS of $(*)$.
\begin{eqnarray}
{\|f\|}_{H^{n/2}} &=& {\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}{(1+\|\xi\|^2)}^{n/2} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi\right)}^{1/2} \\
& \le & c {\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}(1+\|\xi\|^n) |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi\right)}^{1/2} \\
&=& c {\left(\|f\|^2_{L^2} + \|\Delta^{n/4} f\|^2_{L^2}\right)}^{1/2} \\
& \le & c \|f\|_{W^{n/2,2}} \:.
\end{eqnarray}
So it seems to me that we have proved that $W^{n/2,2}(\Bbb R^n) \hookrightarrow H^{n/2}(\Bbb R^n)$, with the inclusion being continuous. Then it would be enough to get that

$W^{n/2,2}(B)\nsubseteq L^\infty(B) \cdots (**)$

Is (**) true? Can we get a proof or a reference for this? Or is there some alternative approach to get (*) ?
Thanks in advance for help!

First, keywords. A more appropriate term to describe the problem is "Endpoint Sobolev estimate/embedding". Endpoint is the word used by analysts to describe "borderline" estimates. Knowing this, you could look for references yourself.
I can't find the same question on this website, so I will give my answer. I will also edit the title of the post so people can find it in the future.

I will answer about estimate $(*)$. Edit: We replace the ball $B$ with the space $\mathbb R^n$ without loss of strength of the result, since if the estimate with $\mathbb R^n$ is false, then the estimate with $B$ is also false (see the "Edit 1" below).
We give an example of a function $f\in H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)\setminus L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. Consider
$$ g(\xi)=\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{n/4}\log^{0.9}(e+|\xi|^2)}. $$
After a direct verification, this function is in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. So, we consider the function $f$ with fourier transform
$$ \hat f(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{-n/4}g(\xi). $$
You can check that $f\in H^{n/2}(\mathbb R)$, and you can notice that $\hat f$ fails to be in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ by a logarithmic error. We claim that $f\not\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.
To verify the last statement, consider the mollification $f_\varepsilon$ with Fourier transform
$$
\hat {f_\varepsilon}(\xi)=\hat f(\xi) \chi(\varepsilon \xi)=\widehat{f*\varphi_\varepsilon}(\xi),
$$
where $\chi=\hat \varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ is real, radial, radially decreasing, non-negative, with $\int_{\mathbb R} \varphi\,dx=\chi(0)=1$, and $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)=\varepsilon^{-n}\varphi(\varepsilon^{-1}x)$.
By contradiction, if $f\in L^\infty$, it holds by Young's convolution inequality
$$ \|f_\varepsilon\|_{L^\infty}\leq \|f\|_{\infty}\|\varphi_\varepsilon\|_{L^1}=\|f\|_{\infty}\|\varphi\|_{L^1}\leq C\|f\|_{L^\infty}. $$
So, the family $f_\varepsilon$ has to be bounded in $L^\infty$.
It is immediate to verify that $\hat{f_\varepsilon}\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, so $f_\varepsilon$ is continuous (it is actually smooth), and
$$
\begin{aligned}
  f_\varepsilon(0)&=C\int_{\mathbb R} \hat f(\xi) \chi(\varepsilon \xi)\\
  &=C\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{n/2}\log^{0.9}(e+|\xi|^2)}\chi(\varepsilon \xi)\\
  &\to +\infty \text{ as }\varepsilon\to 0^+
\end{aligned}
$$
by monone convergence theorem. So the family $f_{\varepsilon}$ is unbounded in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, hence $f\not\in L^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$.

One can also verify in the above construction that the family $f_\varepsilon$ is bounded in $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$, and it is unbounded in $L^\infty$ as we said, so this construction directly disproves the estimate $(*)$.

Remark 1:
There are different kinds of examples that work better in the case where $n/2$ is integer, see e.g. Remark 16, Chapter 9 of the book by H. Brezis "Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDE" for $n=2$. A similar example that should work for all even $n$ is
$$
f(x)=\log(\log(e+1/|x|)):
$$
it works for $n=2$, I think it works for even $n$ but I haven't checked, and I am not sure if it would still be a counterexample for odd $n$ (it probably is if it is for even $n$).
Remark 2:
The same problem can be formulated for Sobolev spaces with $p\neq 2$. It is possible to define $H^s_p(\mathbb R^n)$ in a similar way, and for $1<p<\infty$ it still holds $H^s_p(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ if and only if $s>n/p$. So, the endpoint embedding $s=n/p$ fails.
Remark 3:
One can prove a weaker version of the endpoint Sobolev embedding. Functions in $H^{n/p}_p$ have bounded mean oscillation:
$$ H^{n/p}_p\hookrightarrow \mathrm{BMO}(\mathbb R^n). $$
See e.g. the lecture notes Math 247A (Graduate Fourier analysis) F'06 on Terence Tao's webpage (notes 5: Fefferman-Stein inequality, pseudodifferential operators, Sobolev spaces).

Edit 1.
Let me clarify the role of $B$ here. What I proved is that $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$ is not contained in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, and the bound
$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C \|f\|_{H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)} $$
does not hold for any constant $C>0$. This also proves that $(*)$ does not hold for any $c_B>0$ and for any ball $B$.
Proof. The reason is that, if the estimate holds true for some $\bar B$, $c_{\bar B}$, by translating $f$ and by the translation invariance of the $L^\infty$ and $H^s$ norms, you obtain that the estimate
$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty({\bar B}+v)}\leq c_{\bar B} \|f\|_{H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)} $$
holds true for any $v\in \mathbb R^n$. The ball ${\bar B}+v$ is just the translation of ${\bar B}$ by the vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$. Note that the constant $c_{\bar B}$ does not depend on $v$. Note that the family of balls $$ \{{\bar B}+v\,|\,v\in \mathbb R^n\} $$
covers the whole $\mathbb R^n$. By taking the supremum over all $v\in \mathbb R^n$, you get the estimate
$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C_{\bar B} \|f\|_{H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)}, $$
which is not true by what we have proved before. $\square$

Edit 2.
Concerning $(**)$, you should state precisely what is your definition of $W^{n/2,2}(B)$ in the case where $n$ is odd. It's true for even $n$, and also for odd $n$ with the definition given here (edit: with that definition, using the equivalence of $H^s$ and $W^{s,2}$ norms on $\mathbb R^n$, it follows that any $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$ function lies in $W^{n/2,2}(B)$ when restricted to $B$.)(I think all reasonable definitions of $W^{s,p}(B)$ are equivalent to that given in the article for $p=2$).
For even $n$, you can take the $\log \log$ example I gave in Remark 1 and multiply it by a smooth cutoff function supported in $B(0,1/2)$ which is positive at the origin. This new function will still be (essentially) unbounded, it will lie again in $W^{n/2,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ by iterated Leibniz rule, and it is identically zero in a neighbourhood of $B(0,1)^c$, so it will lie in $W^{n/2,2}(B(0,1))\setminus L^\infty(B(0,1))$. Rescaling and traslating the function will produce a counterexample for an arbitrary ball $B(x,r)$.
Alternatively, you could consider a cutoff funtion $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ supported on $B(0,3/4)$ with $\rho(0)\equiv 1$ in $B(0,1/2)$, and let $F(x)=\rho(x)f(x)$, where $f$ is the same function in my first example. Since $\hat\rho\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, and $\hat F=\hat\rho*\hat f$, it is relatively easy to show that $F\in H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$. If you consider the mollification $F_\varepsilon(x):=F*\varphi_\varepsilon(x)$, you can check by hand that for $\varepsilon$ small enough, $F_\varepsilon\equiv f_\varepsilon$ on $B(0,1/2-\varepsilon)$, assuming $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi)\subset B(0,1)$. So the same argument as before applies, since it also holds
$$ F_\varepsilon(0)=f_{\varepsilon}(0)\to+\infty\text{ as }\varepsilon\to 0. $$
This new function $F$ will then be in $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)\setminus L^\infty(B(0,1))$, and is supported on a ball. This is true for every $n\geq 1$. Now for even $n$, $H^{n/2}=W^{n/2,2}$, so
$$ F\in W_0^{n/2,2}(\mathbb R^n)\setminus L^\infty(B(0,1)) $$
and it is identically zero on $B(0,3/4)$, so
$$F\in W_0^{n/2,2}(B(0,1))\setminus L^\infty(B(0,1))\subset W^{n/2,2}(B(0,1))\setminus L^\infty(B(0,1)).$$
For odd $n$ this also gives a counterexample because, as we said above, if $h\in H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$, then $h|_B\in W^{n/2,2}(B)$ for any ball $B$. (Now that I read this again, the cutoff was not needed to answer your original question, it was enough to restrict the functions on $B$, but it is good to know that such counterexamples exist that are compactly supported).

Please note that on the LHS of $(*)$, one has $L^\infty(B)$ for a ball $B$, not $L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$. So I think if someone has something like that $f$ itself blows up near $0$, then we are through. So can we modify the $log (log (e+\frac{1}{|x|}))$ example, like making it compactly supported near $0$ and then try to show that it belongs to $H^{n/2}$ ? Also if you really want to edit the title of my question, make it $L^\infty(B)$, not $L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$!

So, I re-edited the title (oops). I added a remark on the problem on the ball $B$ in Edit 1, it should be enough to answer your question on $(*)$ (I overlooked the ball initially). Also, in Edit 2 I give some details on localized versions of the above examples.

The $L^\infty$ norms are taken on balls, not on $\Bbb R^n$. Hence by translating when you are moving from one ball to another why should the $L^\infty$ norm be translation invariant?!

I am saying that if you have $f\in L^\infty(B)$ and you set $g(x):=f(x-v)$, then $g\in L^\infty(B+v)$ and the two $L^\infty$ norms coincide. This is true for any $f$ measurable defined on $B$ (or on any other measurable set containing $B$). It is verified just by the definition of essential supremum and the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure. I would call this property translation invariance or translation symmetry of the $L^\infty$ norm.

With that definition, what you are getting is $|g|{L^\infty(B+v)} \le C_B |f|{H^{n/2}}$, and hence you are getting the inequality on the translated ball for a different function! This doesn't imply $|f|{L^\infty(B+v)} \le C_B |f|{H^{n/2}}$, what you have written in Edit 1! You have to understand that what you've got is a global unboundedness, and what we are looking for is a local unboundedness, a much more nontrivial problem! And may I know why did you replace $L^\infty(B)$ by $L^\infty$ in the title, once again?

I removed $B$ in the title on a second thought because from a set point of view it doesn't make sense to ask whether $H^{n/2}(\mathbb R^n)$ embeds into $L^\infty(B)$. The restriction map would not be injective. I get that the question itself is about local boundedness, I just wanted to keep the title simple so that the post can be searched easily. When editing it the last time I couldn't think of a better title, so I simply removed my mistake. If you have a better title in mind feel free to edit it, at this point you should choose what is a good title if you don't like my vague version

Yes, but the $H^{n/2}$ norm is also translation invariant, so you have $|g|{H^{n/2}}=|f|{H^{n/2}}$. So you get $|g|{L^\infty(B+v)}\leq c{B} |g|_{H^{n/2}}$, the desired inequality with $g$ instead of $f$. Since $f$ is arbitrary, $g$ is arbitrary as well, so you have proved the inequality for all functions. I understand that you ask for local unboundedness. If you read my first edit, what I am telling you in my answer is precisely that the two $L^\infty$ estimates (local and global) are equivalent because of translation invariance.
